# Get the first column of a dataframe using iloc[0] throws "IndexError : Single positional indexer out of bounds"

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a structure dataframe and I am trying to get the first column using

offset = 128

```
row = struct.loc[struct['Offset']==offset].iloc[0]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwhxm.png)

Comment: Do you mean, you want to get all rows where 'Offset' value is 128? If so, `struct[struct['Offset']==128]` should work

Answer (score 0):

If this is your df:

```
struct = pd.DataFrame({
    'Offset': [164, 128],
    'size': [128,36],
    'param': ['Data1', 'Data2'],
    'Address': ['0x0A', '0x0A']    
})
```

And what you want is subset the first column with `iloc`, this should do it:

```
struct.iloc[:,0]
```

If not, please clarify.